# How to get the value printed when it is under react text in selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Please find the attached screenshot for html tags:[We need to print the 3 which in react-text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otUrw.png)

The following code i have tried:
    WebElement MyText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='badge-number'])[6]"));

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

String platformName = (String) jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].value;", MyText);
System.out.println("text:"+MyText.getText());

I just want to print that minutes and seconds and they are dynamic.

Comment: <div class="badge-number">
 <!-- react-text: 659 -->
 "3"
 <!-- /react-text: 659 -->
<span class="badge-small-text hour">Minutes</span>
 <!-- react-text: 660 -->
 "12"
 <!-- /react-text: 660 -->
<span class="badge-small-text hour">Seconds</span>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best solution but with react is kind a hard - so I can suggest getting the page source from the selenium driver then use some regex to extract what you need (like groups between the " char and also between the span elements.